# RSI over bought and sold for multiple assets

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI Cross 80 & 20 - Screener', shorttitle='RSI - Screener', overlay=true, precision=6)

i_alert_mode = input.string(defval="once_per_bar", title='Alerts Mode', options=["all", "once_per_bar", "once_per_bar_close"], group='Alert')

rsiPeriod = input.int(14, title="RSI Period", minval=1)
rsiOverbought = input(80, title="Overbought Level")
rsiOversold = input(20, title="Oversold Level")

RSI = ta.rsi(close, rsiPeriod)

lCond = RSI >= rsiOverbought
sCond = RSI <= rsiOversold

finalL = lCond and not lCond[1]
finalS = sCond and not sCond[1]

plotshape(finalL, 'Long', shape.flag, location.abovebar, color.rgb(175, 127, 76), size=size.small)
plotshape(finalS, 'Short', shape.flag, location.belowbar, color.rgb(175, 127, 76), size=size.small)

tickerString = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT,BINANCE:ETHUSDT,BINANCE:FLOWUSDT,BINANCE:NEARUSDT"

var bool[] finalLs = array.new_bool(0)
var bool[] finalSs = array.new_bool(0)
tickers = str.split(tickerString, ",")

for i = 0 to array.size(tickers)-1
    [ls, ss] = request.security(syminfo.prefix + ":" + tickers[i], timeframe.period, [finalL, finalS])
    array.push(finalLs, ls)
    array.push(finalSs, ss)

for i = 0 to array.size(tickers)-1
    if array.get(finalLs, i)
        alert('Buy Signal: ' + tickers[i] + ' : Timeframe: ' + timeframe.period, i_alert_mode)

    if array.get(finalSs, i)
        alert('Sell Signal: ' + tickers[i] + ' : Timeframe: ' + timeframe.period, i_alert_mode)
```

I wanted to implement this script but I got these errors:

```
8:10:40 PM  Error at 31:56 Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='call 'operator SQBR' (string\[\])'. An argument of 'string\[\]' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected.

8:10:40 PM  Error at 37:32 Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='call 'operator SQBR' (string\[\])'. An argument of 'string\[\]' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.

8:10:40 PM  Error at 40:33 Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr1'='call 'operator SQBR' (string\[\])'. An argument of 'string\[\]' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to access array value in pinescript is : array.get(NameOfArray, Index).

You should replace :

```
tickers[i]
```

with

```
array.get(tickers,i)
```